# How to batch to space [n*7,12] to [n,7,12]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I believe `tf.batch_to_space_nd` is what I need for this task, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this indexing and shape/rank business.

What I'd like to do is , from the input tensor with shape [n*7, 12] take the first 7 rows and put them in a separate dimension. Than take the next 7 rows, etc. The final shape should than be: [n,7,12].

Possibly I could simply add or squeeze a dimension, e.g. input could be [n*7, 12, 1, 1] and output could be [n,7,12,1]. I believe this can be done with batch_to_space_nd or possibly with tf.gather_nd or one of the other [slice and join](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_guides/python/array_ops#Slicing_and_Joining) operations, but haven't found the right combination.

Or do I really have to slice and stack? I know how to do that, but seems unnecessarily ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can simply use tf.reshape.

```
# Assuming x has shape [n*7, 12], y will have shape [n, 7, 12]
y = tf.reshape(x, [n, 7, 12])
```